# Wringing a torus around the circumference of its major radius

Tags: animation

Would it be possible to wring the tube of a torus around the circumference of its major radius, like this?

[image]

This was done by shifting the texture coordinates by using a Texture mapping node. However, the object I have in mind would be low poly and flat shaded, i.e. the location of the edges would be visible, so texture shifting would make the texture slide over the torus rather than giving the appearance of the tube being wrung.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that actually the minor radius?

Comment: As far as I see it, the tube rotates around the circumference of the major radius.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for pointing it out though. I hope my edit made it clearer. To be specific, what happens here is that any circular cross section of the tube rotates around the normal to its plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use a cylinder with array and curve modifier :

[image]

apply the array modifier and Unwrap the cylinder then you can get the result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I [got it](http://i.imgur.com/Y7AgGSo.gif) :) (Though I need to get the length of the cylinder better fitted to the length of the curve).

Comment: @SixthOfFour the length was a problem I didn't use fit_curve it was leaving some gap i had to proximate it, just resize the curve slowly

Comment: It's just a little math. I used a bezier circle with default settings. If I use a circle with the same number of sections as the cylinder, it'll be easier.